# Can't test my android application on my phone

Tags: android, adt

I want to test my application on my Android phone.

But this phone is connected to pc, but doesn't show up in ADT devices list.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled on the device?

Comment: There are endless guides for this all over the internet. What steps have you followed so far?

Comment: Could you find Developer option in the setting? Which Android version do you have?

Comment: you must active Developer option on your device

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-debugging-on-real-device/ is nice tutorial

Comment: install driver of your phone in your pc ..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure you have the Developer Options enabled on the device (and 'Allow USB Debugging' selected).  Also you need (on Windows) to have the device USB driver installed.

Also, sometimes you need to restart ADB after the device has been connected.

From Eclipse, open the DDMS perspective, and in the devices list, click the upside triangle to access the menu to restart ADB (don't worry about the failed to restart errors you will see those always).

Also, you can restart from the command line with the following commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Sync(pc suite) of the mobile device in the system and even unable the USB debugging in the mobile

Answer (score 0):

Which phone are you using?

If it's a Nexus device, you have to install the Google USB Driver. You can follow [this guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) to install the driver.